# Debug a flat assembly binary

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm new to the assembly and low level programming
I'm using FASM in windows xp. when I assemble the bellow code it gives me a .bin file.

```
data1 db 25
data2 db 10001001b
data3 db 12h
      org 0x10
data4 db '2367'
      org 0x18
data5 db ?
      org 0x20
data6 db 'Hello there'
```

The book I'm learning is using windows debug command to see the values and address of each command but when I use debug it shows something else

My question is is there any application that can debug these files? even the bootloader assembly binaries?

Comment: Ndisasm will attempt to disassemble it... but I don't think you'll find it useful. What. if anything, is this code supposed to do?

Comment: Its just a test. I'm learning assembly and I just want to see how does it stores the data

Comment: Maybe "hiew" or "biew" (I think they call it "bye" now). The 'd' command to DEBUG should do it, too. Or... it isn't too difficult to write your own hexdump routine. I don't think you want to actually "debug" or "disassemble" it. A bootloader, you might want to disassemble. It probably won't "debug" very well - loaded at the wrong address...

Comment: Thanks but I need a free application hiew and biew aren't free
Is there any way to use ollydbg to disassemble a 16bit assembly application?

Answer (score 0):

Using 'org' directives to put variables at specific locations works in MASM, but not in FASM or NASM.

With FASM and NASM you have to do it like this:

```
data1 db 25                       // 0x00
data2 db 10001001b                // 0x01
data3 db 12h                      // 0x02
      times 0x10 - ($-$$) db 0
data4 db '2367'                   // 0x10
      times 0x18 - ($-$$) db 0
data5 db '?'                      // 0x18
      times 0x20 - ($-$$) db 0
data6 db 'Hello there'            // 0x20
```

You can then assemble as a flat binary and check the result with hexdump:

```
00000000  19 89 12 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000010  32 33 36 37 00 00 00 00  3f 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |2367....?.......|
00000020  48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 74 68  65 72 65                 |Hello there|
```

You should read sections [2.2.3](http://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=manual#2.2.3) and [2.2.4](http://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=manual#2.2.4) of the FASM manual.

Comment: Oh really thanks Antoine. It worked well
Can I use this method for a complete bootloader that assembled with NASM?